# How can I reset all of my MS Office preferences?

Tags: microsoft-office

I have been working at the same organization for over a decade.  Every time my computer gets upgraded, all of my settings are migrated.  However, I have some settings in MS Office that appear to be giving me grief, and I don't know which of the zillion settings is responsible for this grief.

Is there any way to reset all of my MS Office preferences and settings to their defaults?

For reference, I'm currently running MS Office 2013 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

In short: your settings could be anywhere.

If you are convinced this is a problem that is affecting only you, and it follows you from machine to machine, it is possible there is something in your User Profile that is at fault.

Many user settings are stored in "%userProfile%\AppData", however other fragments of configuration may be stored elsewhere (such as in the registry).

The specifics of your configuration would be known by your IT department - I would strongly urge you to contact them for advice about your specific configuration.

In your position, I would ask for a new User Account and compare the difference in experience - if it's better, look to migrate to the new user account; if the problem persists, you know that the problem lays outside your own profile.

If you list some specific symptoms, the community may be able to provide a more targeted answer.

I wish you the best of luck.